# Can I rewrite propositional formula in this way?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, propositional-calculus, conjunctive-normal-form

I have a propositional formula:

$$(\neg p \lor \neg q \lor r)$$

Can i rewrite it in this way?:

$$(\neg p \lor \neg q \lor r) = (\neg p \lor (q \land \neg r))= (\neg p \lor q) \land (\neg p \lor \neg r))$$

Comment: That first equality is definitely incorrect: if $p$ is true and $q$ is false, then $(\neg p\vee\neg q\vee r)$ is true but $(\neg p\vee (q\wedge\neg r))$ is false. (Maybe there's an order of operations issue here; remember, "$\neg$" binds more tightly than "$\vee$," so that "$(\neg p\vee \neg q\vee r)$" is shorthand for "$(((\neg p)\vee (\neg q))\vee r)$.")

Comment: @NoahSchweber so it not possible to make it cnf with two values in each clause?

Comment: It is in fact not possible - see my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, that's incorrect. Specifically, the first claimed equality is wrong. For example, if $p$ is true and $q$ is false then $(\neg p\vee\neg q\vee r)$ is true but $(\neg p\vee (q\wedge\neg r))$ is false.

Per the comments, it seems that your goal is to convert your original formula into a $2$-CNF formula, that is, a conjunction of disjunctions of pairs of [literals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Literal_(mathematical_logic)). **This can't be done**, for a very strong reason:

> Can you show that in fact your formula does not imply *any* formula of the form $r_0\vee r_1$ for $r_0,r_1$ literals?

Comment: thanks, could you please check one more my question https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3864487/apply-resolution-algorithm-to-check-sat-for-cnf ? its kind of more complicated though

Comment: @irate_mastermind - What's the point of asking for a help for [another question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3864487/288417) and then deleting that question after receiving an answer?

Comment: @Taroccoesbrocco solved it by myself and then saw your solution. its similar though so i accept it

Comment: @irate_mastermind - Other people might be interested in your question and its solution. So, there is no point to delete it. If you find a solution, you can answer your own question.

Answer (score 1):

You forgot a negation in the second expression, $(\neg p \lor (q \land \neg r))$. The correct expression should be $(\neg p \lor \neg(q \land \neg r))$ (De Morgan's Laws). Hope this helps!